# Is it possible to move the location pointer up or down with MS Word Javascript API

Tags: ms-word, ms-office, office-js, word-addins

I am currently working on a plugin which will take voice commands and upon receiving a response from the server, act accordingly. For example if i say "delete word", the last word will be deleted. I want to be able to move the pointer left/right/up one line/down one line. Does Word Javascript API provide a way to achieve this?

Comment: Your code deletes _all_ the words in the current selection, starting with the first. But your method is named `deleteLastWord` and your description of the problem doesn't match the code. Please clarify. (Did you paste in the wrong code?)

Comment: I edited my question and deleted the unnecessary part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no cursor movement APIs. But there are methods on the Paragraph object for getting the previous paragraph and the next paragraph. There are also ways to move among Ranges, if you can get a collection or an array of the ranges that you want to move around. And you can find the `AdjacentAfter` and `AdjacentBefore` ranges using the `Range.compareLocationWith` method. The Range object also has `getNextRange` and `getNextRangeOrNullObject` methods. Finally, the `Range.select("Start")` and `Range.select("End")` will put the cursor just before/after the current selected range.